# Можно ли произносить слово "гололедица" как "гололёдица"?

Tags: существительные

Недавно я услышал от одного человека вот такой вариант произношения слова "гололедица" — "голол**ё**дица" через Ё. Можно ли так произносить слово "гололедица" через **Ё**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это распространенная ошибка. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но этот вариант более логичен, потому что "гололёд", а не "гололед". Поэтому людям так удобнее говорить.